# Wrong parameters

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax

so consider this case:

> The workspace is a website similar to Google Drive. (Keep that in Mind)

I have a Delete `.icon`  to delete a file from  my files list,

and as soon as i request delete file WebMethod using *Ajax*
i would like to also retrieve the new files array,
within the same response.

So far i have Tried this.

consider also that the work flow is -

1- request Delete file using Ajax from the *Element ID*

2- after deleting (that is successfully already done) i call another function that retrieve the **files**   from their `RealPath`

> RealPath : is where those files Placed on the serve.

So far this is the code i have Tried.

```
 $(".fa-trash-o").click(function () {
    var ID = $(this).closest(".ImageBlock").attr('id');
    var path = $(this).closest(".ImageBlock").attr('Get')
    var RealID = parseInt(ID);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../../Home.aspx/DeleteFile",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'ID': RealID, 'RealPath': path }),
        success: function (result, xhr, request) {

            OnSuccess(result.d);

        }
    });



});
```

and this is my Back-end webMethod

```
public static string DeleteFile(int ID, string RealPath)
    {
        try


      {

                FilesBAL FilesBAL = new FilesBAL();
                if (FilesBAL.Delete(ID) == true) {
                return GetDataByParent(RealPath);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Statment.Error_Delete;

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Statment.Error_Delete;
            }

        }
```

> GetDataByParent: A method that returns Data serialized as *JSON*
>
> Additional info might be needed: i am using `MySql` StoredProcedures to execute the `DB` queries.

What are the Steps to check on that ? 
Since the same method (`GetDataByParent`) used before to get the home page files is used when deletion occur, And it works 100% fine everywhere else.

Comment: What stored procedure?  What path?  Where specifically is the problem occurring and what are the runtime values when that happens?  When you debug, where should that value be coming from and where in the sequence of events is it lost?

Comment: sorry for  not explaining that . basicly this should work after i click the delete button  , then the ajax request should take the path and the id of the checked item , to send it to the back-end code the problem occurring as soon as i hit delete button , the item is deleted but in the same time i have to get my new items data to show on the page so i use the path of this file wich is were its location to get all other files that have the same location for example the path is /root i send that to ajax and on ,

Comment: and that gets my json file with all the data that are in /root .. problem is the new json file is empty so the page wont load anything

Comment: This would be a good time to familiarize yourself with the use of debuggers.  Mostly because we can't debug this on your computer for you, but also because this will help you solve problems in code yourself (which has a *much* faster turnaround time than Stack Overflow ever will).  When you run your application in debug mode, does the server-side code ever receive a valid path value from the request?  When you use your browser's debugging tools, does the AJAX request include the values you expect it to?  You need to find specifically where the value is being lost.

Comment: the value passed by ajax is valid but after that in the back-end its lost for example ajax sent /Root ... in my data access layer the parameter is taking string of /Root\\ or something like that ! and thats not valid somehow it adding extra characters ! and ill work more focused and try to debug again , thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it passes a wrong retrieved `RealPath` parameter from the `Stored Procedure` .

Using some Debugging Tips i found [here](https://michaelscodingspot.com/2018/01/09/7-debugging-techniques-know-c-net/)